# Is there a way to flip y-axes ticks on ggsurvplot without changing the results?

Tags: r, axis-labels, survival-analysis, survminer

I am using survival analysis to show the proportion of individuals/duration to reach a developmental milestone, and I would like to flip the y-axis ticks so it has 0 at the top and 1.00 at the bottom. I tried using scale_y_reverse, but this flipped the results too. I just want the axis ticks to go from 0-1, while maintaining the visuals of the first graph. Thanks for your help!!

```
ggsurvplot(spin_fit, data = spin.data, pval = TRUE, conf.int =  TRUE) 
ggplot2 <- ggsurvplot(spin_fit, data = spin.data, pval = TRUE)$plot
df1 <- data.frame(time=spin_fit$time, nRisk=spin_fit$n.risk, nRiskRel=spin_fit$n.risk/max(spin_fit$n.risk))  
ggplot2 + geom_point(aes(x=time, y=nRiskRel), data = df1, alpha=0.5, size=3)
ggplot2 + ylab("Proportion of Larvae Spinning Cocoon") ]
```

[image: survival plot not flipped]

Here's what happened when I added to the last line:
`ggplot2 + ylab("Proportion of Larvae Spinning Cocoon") + scale_y_reverse()`

[image: survival plot flipped]

Comment: What if you subtract nRiskRel from 1? `....y=1-nRiskRel....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use [`scale_y_continuous`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html) to set your own breaks and labels:

```r
break_values <- c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)
ggplot2 + scale_y_continuous(breaks = break_values,
                             labels = as.character(rev(break_values)))
```

Answer (score 2):

ggsurvplot also natively supports this without manually messing with the scales through the `fun` argument.

From the help section:

> fun: an arbitrary function defining a transformation of the survival curve. Often used transformations can be specified with a character argument: "event" plots cumulative events (f(y) = 1-y), "cumhaz" plots the cumulative hazard function (f(y) = -log(y)), and "pct" for survival probability in percentage.

So all you need to do is:

```
ggplot2 <- ggsurvplot(spin_fit, data = spin.data, pval = TRUE, fun = "event")$plot
```